# Upgrading Airflow Deployment via Helm

Tags: postgresql, airflow, alembic

I am running a helm upgrade --install on an airflow deployment the current deployment is on version 2.6 and the new version is also on 2.6 and the base image is the same the difference is new details being added to values.yml file however I keep getting from the db migration k8s pod that it cannot find the dB hash xxxxx which is the dB schema for airflow 2.6 it current has the schema for airflow 2.5.

My option is to downgrade the live database but the process of backup and others problems is why I am seeking a second opinion if anyone has solved this

Answer (score 0):

I think some of your customizations are bringing airflow version to a previous one. When you are installing extra dependencies. `pip` works in the way that it treats `airflow` as any other dependency, so if it finds out that the best way to resolve your dependencies is to downgrade airflow - it will do so.

This can happen for example when dependency you try to install conflicts with new version of Airflow.

You can easily check what the problem is (And actually this is a recommended way to install extra dependencies):

If you are installing dependencies in Airlfow image based on 2.6.1

```bash
pip install apache-airflow==2.6.1 your-dependency==xxx
```

or

```bash
pip install apache-airflow==2.6.1 -r requirements.txt
```

will never downgrade airflow - if you have conflicts in your dependencies, it will fail and print what the conflict is.